# Is 'sola gratia' as a soteriology traceable in the period leading to the Protestant Reformation?

Tags: history, protestantism, reformation, grace, sola-gratia

Protestants often consider the Roman Catholic church to have significantly distorted the gospel. Were there Christians prior to the Reformation who had essentially the same understanding of the doctrines of salvation (particularly *sola gratia*) as the later Reformers did? I'm interested in people between Augustine (approx. 400 AD) and Luther (1517 AD).

Comment: Related: Compare the difference between "Protestants" and "Reformational Catholics" in [this article](http://www.firstthings.com/onthesquare/2013/11/the-end-of-protestantism).

Comment: Research Monergism -- it was a theology alive and well in the early Church, and it was rejected and condemned officially around at 6th Ecumenical council in 680. 

And FYI your question is a tad presumptuous. The thinking is typically the Catholics added to the Gospel, not distorted.

Answer (score 1):

Another theologian who anticipated some of the important thoughts of the Reformation, including *sola gratia*, was [Bernard of Clairvaux (1090-1153)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_of_Clairvaux), who was frequently cited by both Luther and Calvin.

Answer (score 0):

Just to list some:

- [John Wycliffe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wycliffe) (1320-1384 AD)
- [Jan Hus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Hus) (1369-1415 AD)
- [Jerome of Prague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome_of_Prague)  (1379-1416 AD)
- [Peter Waldo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Waldo) (1140–1218 AD)
- [Girolamo Savonarola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girolamo_Savonarola) (1452–1498 AD)

Comment: Could you add summaries of the significant points in these men's theology that make you think they fit the bill for this question? How did each of them express their ideas on soteriology?

Answer (score -3):

Yes. They were called heretics. Augustine probably would not have even needed to write about it if it weren't for Pelagius. You can read all about early views like the ransom theory, Abelard's idealistic view on moral influence, Anselm's notion of satisfaction of God's honor in the 11th century and not to mention earlier views seen as heretical like Origen's recapitulation theory which said that demons and the Satan will be be fully justified in the end at Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atonement_in_Christianity I could type it all here but to copy would be plagiarising and why do all work for you. You want to learn, read. Best book on early views of salvation is Gustaf Aulen Christus Victor which is cheap on amazon but also can be in your library if your country has them [http://www.amazon.com/Christus-Victor-Historical-Study-Atonement/dp/1592443303](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592443303)

Comment: Do any of those have a protestant understanding of salvation? I'm not familiar with them, but recapitulation certainly isn't!